# Missing AD module and can't get it, need something similar or something to simulate it

Tags: powershell, active-directory, updates

So I'm trying to output a complete KB list for all computers on a server (which works on one computer) but it doesn't recognize `Get-ADcomputer` as a cmdlet. When checking various sources, it appears that the AD module isn't included. As I'm doing this on a work computer/server I'm hesitant to download anything or anything of that nature.

Is there any way I can achieve the following without using the AD module or someway I might be missing how to import the module (if it exists, which I don't think it does on this system)?

```
# 1. Define credentials
$cred = Get-Credential
# 2. Define a scriptblock
$sb = {
    $Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
    $Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    $HistoryCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()

    $Searcher.QueryHistory(0,$HistoryCount) | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $Title = $null
        if ($_.Title -match "\(KB\d{6,7}\)") {
            # Split returns an array of strings
            $Title = ($_.Title -split '.*\((?<KB>KB\d{6,7})\)')[1]
        } else {
            $Title = $_.Title
        }

        $Result = $null
        switch ($_.ResultCode) {
            0 { $Result = 'NotStarted'}
            1 { $Result = 'InProgress' }
            2 { $Result = 'Succeeded' }
            3 { $Result = 'SucceededWithErrors' }
            4 { $Result = 'Failed' }
            5 { $Result = 'Aborted' }
            default { $Result = $_ }
        }
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            InstalledOn = Get-Date -Date $_.Date;
            Title = $Title;
            Name = $_.Title;
            Status = $Result
        }
    } | Sort-Object -Descending:$false -Property InstalledOn | Where {
        $_.Title -notmatch "^Definition\sUpdate"
    }
}

#Get all servers in your AD (if less than 10000)
Get-ADComputer -ResultPageSize 10000 -SearchScope Subtree -Filter {
    (OperatingSystem -like "Windows*Server*")
} | ForEach-Object {
    # Get the computername from the AD object
    $computer = $_.Name
    # Create a hash table for splatting
    $HT = @{
        ComputerName = $computer ;
        ScriptBlock = $sb ;
        Credential = $cred;
        ErrorAction = "Stop";
    }
    # Execute the code on remote computers
    try {
        Invoke-Command @HT
    } catch {
        Write-Warning -Message "Failed to execute on $computer because $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
} | Format-Table PSComputerName,Title,Status,InstalledOn,Name -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got 3 options:

- First is to just install the RSAT feature for AD which will include the AD module.  This is probably the best option unless there is something specific preventing it.  If you're running your script from a client operating systems you need to install the [RSAT](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2202.remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-client-and-windows-server-dsforum2wiki.aspx) first, though.
- Option 2 (which should only be used if adding the Windows feature is somehow an issue) is to download and use the Quest AD tools, which give very similar functionality, but it looks like Dell is doing their best to hide these now so that may be difficult to locate...
- Option 3 is to use the .NET ADSI classes to access AD directly, which will work without any additional downloads on any system capable of running PowerShell.  If you'd like to go this route you should check out the documentation for the interface [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170.aspx) and for the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx).

**Edit**

Just noticed the last part of your question, what do you mean by "a complete KB list"? Not just Windows updates or things updated manually or whatever?  What else would be in a list of Windows updates that was not a Windows update?

Comment: I'll be sure to look into those

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the OSes you are using but in general if you have a server 2008 R2 or above, all you have to do it activate the RSAT feature AD PowerShell Module and you will have the cmdlet you are looking for.

On a client machine, you 'have to' install RSAT, and then activate the features. You can take a look at the technet article for more info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449483(v=ws.10).aspx

If you don't want to use that option, then you will have to use .NET ADSI classes. There are tons of examples on how to do this, it basically boils down to a couple of lines really. Technet has examples on this as well: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730967.aspx

Comment: From what I can tell this is 2009 but for whatever reason the AD module isn't included. I'll be sure to look into those

Comment: You must mean 2008, there is no 2009 :) But yes, by default RSAT will be installed yet not activated. You use dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:the_full_path_to_feature syntax. You can get the names of features using dism /online /get-features

One thing you need to be careful is that you cannot simply enable the child feature without first enabling the parent if you will do this from command line. Optionally, simply launch appwiz.cpl > Optional Features on the left, and enable RSAT.